# How to get the total supply of the smart contract in pallet?

Tags: smart-contract

In my pallet I want to get the total supply of a given smart contract ERC20.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked whether or not this compiles, but it should give you a starting point.

The original code I based this off [this example](https://github.com/justinFrevert/Runtime-Contract-Interactions/blob/master/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L88).

```rust
// We need to add the Contracts pallet here
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_contracts::Config {
    ...
}

// -- snip --

#[pallet::weight(10_000))]
pub fn total_supply(origin: OriginFor<T>, dest: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
    let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

    // As mentioned in https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-22.md#total_supply--balance
    // The `PSP22::total_supply` method has a selector of `0x162df8c2`
    let mut selector: crate::Vec<u8> = [0x16, 0x2d, 0xF8, 0xC2].into();
                                                                                         
    // For this example this is arbitrary
    let gas_limit: Weight = 10_000_000_000;
    let value: BalanceOf<T> = Default::default();
                                                                                         
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    data.append(&mut selector);
                                                                                         
    // Do the actual call to the smart contract function
    pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
        who,
        dest.clone(),
        value,
        gas_limit,
        data,
        false,
    )
    .result?;
                                                                                         
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  But is there way to get the result in the function after executing the bare_call.  I need the result to do some computation like TVL, etc.

Comment: You'll need to dig into the return type of `bare_call`. Eventually you get to `ExecReturnValue` (https://crates.parity.io/pallet_contracts_primitives/struct.ExecReturnValue.html) and from there you should be able to decode the `data` field into a balance. Something like `let balance: T::Balance = Decode::decode(result.data)`, but it'll vary for your specific pallet/runtime

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the contract deployed? Are you using an EVM pallet, or have an ink! contract? If, for instance, you have an ERC20 ink! contract, it has a total supply function by design, so you should be able to call the total_supply functions in the UI https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.  I am using openbrush/ink.  I want to access it using my custom pallet.  I am using bare_call to execute other messages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).